# Can we transfer the control from one tab to another tab using the selenium ide?

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

Can we transfer the control from one tab to another tab using the selenium ide

Answer (score 0):

selectWindow is what you want. Browser Tabs are really just windows, if that's what you mean by tabs.

> selectWindow(windowID) Arguments:
>
> windowID - the JavaScript window ID of the window to select
>
> Selects a popup window using a window locator; once a popup window has
>   been selected, all commands go to that window. To select the main
>   window again, use null as the target.
>
> Window locators provide different ways of specifying the window
>   object: by title, by internal JavaScript "name," or by JavaScript
>   variable.
>
> title=My Special Window: Finds the window using the text that appears
>   in the title bar. Be careful; two windows can share the same title. If
>   that happens, this locator will just pick one.
>
> name=myWindow: Finds the window using its internal JavaScript "name" property. This is the second parameter "windowName" passed to
>   the JavaScript method window.open(url, windowName, windowFeatures,
>   replaceFlag) (which Selenium intercepts).
>
> var=variableName: Some pop-up windows are unnamed (anonymous), but are associated with a JavaScript variable name in the current
>   application window, e.g. "window.foo = window.open(url);". In those
>   cases, you can open the window using "var=foo".

Or do you mean tabs within the web page?